# Passing URL Variables

Tags: php, url, variables

I have a series of pages that share a similar structure but have varying content, which I'll call Page A (could be any one of them).  I also have a single Page B which each page A links to.  All Page A's are WordPress posts with an iframe embedded, and Page B is a WordPress page with an iframe embedded which depends on what the iframe URL was from the referring Page A.  The iframe URLs reference one of a set of static HTML pages (which are different by geography).

I want to pass particular information as variables from each Page A to Page B which will define the iframe on Page B and the URL for certain images.

The first variable is the URL of the iframe on Page A.  The second variable is the geography code also used on Page A, to be used in the middle of several image URL references (i.e., http://mydomain.com/"geography_code"/img.jpg).

My questions:

1. How do I define the static HTML URL used in the Page A iframe as a variable (note: NOT the referring Page A URL but the URL used in the iframe on Page A) in the link to Page B?  Defining the geography is no problem.
2. How do I use the Page A iframe variable as an iframe reference on Page B?
3. How do I use the geography variable in the middle of the image URL on Page B?

Can you please help me with this?  Specific php code would be greatly appreciated.  I've spent quite a bit of time googling and reading related posts without sorting this out.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Cheers,

Brian

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand your problem clearly. So I have provided a common solution for accessing iframe contents in another file. Hope this helps for you.

main.html

```
<html>
<head><title>Parent Page</title></head>
<body>
<h3>Parent Page</h3>
<iframe src="a.html" id="one" name="one"></iframe>

<iframe src="b.html" id="two" name="two"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

child1.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Child 1</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

var var1 = 'Test';

function fun1(txt) {
  document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
IFRAME 1 Content in BODY
<div id="div1">Div content of the iframe 1</div>
</body>
</html>
```

child2.html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<title>Child 2</title>
<body>IFRAME 2<br>

<script type="text/javascript">
function function_in_child2(txt) {
  var res1 = parent.one.document.body.innerHTML; //this gets the content of the IFRAME1 named as "one" in main.html

   alert(res1);         

 var getvar1 = parent.one.var1;   // gets the value of the variable "var1", which is defined in the child1 (iframe1 named as "one" in parent form) 
 document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML = getvar1; //displays the variable var1 in div2

 parent.one.fun1("This value goes to fun1 of child1");  // Calls the function "fun1",  defined in child1
}
</script>
<div id="div2"></div>
<button onclick="function_in_child2('<b>The text changed from iframe 2</b>')">Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

There first file main.html which contains sources of two files a.html and b.html

You can get the content of a.html using the below line in b.html

```
var res1 = parent.one.document.body.innerHTML;
```

You can get the value of variable var1 which is in a.html through the below line

```
var getvar1 = parent.one.var1;
```

You can call the function fun1 which is defined in a.html using the below line

```
parent.one.fun1("This value goes to fun1 of child1");
```